# Why is jQuery .animate() jumpy?

Tags: jquery

On https://xjour.com I have a jumpy navigation animation.

It does jump on FF and Chrome.

Works as expected on Edge and mobile.

I made a JSFiddle to reproduce the problem.

Here it works as expected though.

Please click outside the navigation to close it — not on the links.

https://jsfiddle.net/9kak1088/

The code is nothing more than

```
function open() {


        $('.menu').animate({
            'width':'17vw'
        },100)

        $('html').one('click', close)
}

function close() {

        $('.menu').animate({
            'width':'2.994vw'
        },100)


        $('.menu').one('click',open)
}

$('.menu').one('click',open);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't access to your example site because of secure connexion failed, but it is ok with the fiddle.

jQuery animate used to be an OK solution before CSS3, but it can suffer from some performance problems coming from Javascript. From what i understand, it animates with calculating and moving elements positions based on timeout functions. That can be really jumpy depending on how many elements you animate, or if javascript is really busy doing something else at the time.

A common solution here would be to use CSS3 features that were made specially for this. You can eventually use the jQuery solution as a fallback for old browsers (you have solutions to detect in javascript if CSS3 is supported).

CSS3 transition works by setting transition on a CSS attribute:

```
.menu{
    transition: width 0.1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: width 0.1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.1s linear 0s;
}
```

then, when the attribute value is modified, broswer animates it automatically:

```
$('.menu').css({
    'width':'41vw'
});
```

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fz4pwwjj/2/

Comment: Good explanantion and recommendation. jQuery's `animate()` really should only be used in case transitions don't do the job.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. Can you elaborate on the secure connection problem, please? Because you have — not — seen what I meant. The animation is coded to go smaller. But it first gets bigger, and then smaller. That means a better word for jumpy would be “behaves badly”.

Comment: Hi. Awesome solution. First had to process it. It works. Can you please anyway tell me, what you meant about — not — being able to access the site? Thanks.

Comment: when clicking on the link (firefox), i have this error : `SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE` (maybe it is on my end, because it works on chrome)

Comment: Do you have the developer version of Firefox?

Comment: no, the regular one for the moment, but as i was checking the version, seems that last update from 50.1.0 to 51.0.1 failed, maybe that is why..

Comment: I read that Startcom certificates, which I have, are — not — supported anymore by Firefox. But for me it works. Thanks again.